# How to remove reverse slash from json in axios post request

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Adds reverse slash to json file when sending axios post request .Even though I use replace, backslash is not removed

```
 axios
      .post(
        "https://test-manager/backend",
        {
          gameName: this.gameName,
          platform: this.gamePlatform,
          json: finalData.replace(/\\/g, ""),
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

[image]

Comment: where does `finalData` come from? Seems like it is a string and you wouldn't have the issue if it was an object. It is getting stringified again when axios stringifies the data argument of post()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the stringified json using `JSON.parse` as follows :

```js
json: JSON.parse(finalData),
```